# How do I make functional use of OpenAI Gym when my computer is not able to identify or locate Gym?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have been trying to use gym for a few weeks now. However, I have had no success. I am trying to run this implementation of the CartPole, but I receive a return error:

NotImplementedError: abstract

I have installed gym to the best of my knowledge. However, for whatever reason, I have no functionality when trying to access it.

```
import gym


env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')

for i_episode in range(20):
    env.render()
    print(observation)
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
    if done:
        print('Episode finished after {} timesteps'.format(t+1))
        break
```

A follow up is: are there any other ways to do reinforcement learning on a Mac in Python? OpenAI gym does not seem to be a suitable option due to the lack of helpful supporting documentation or resources.

Comment: Try including information on how you installed gym.  Also, providing the full traceback information helps others determine where the error occurred.   (when I run this code I get `NameError: name 'observation' is not defined` which makes sense).

Comment: A quick google search for `NotImplementedError: abstract` leads to: https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/775 . Does that help? If not, you should indeed add more information like Bill requested

Answer (score 0):

Implementing gym environments can be tricky because gym requires various dependencies with different versions. I think your issue has to do something with your gym installation.

Safest way to install gym and work without any issue is by using a python virtual environment. It is always better to have a separate virtual environment for your gym projects. Please use [conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) or [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#installing-packages-for-your-project) to create a virtual environment.

**Example in pipenv**

install pipenv

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

go inside your project directory ( where your .py file resides )

```
cd myproject
```

install gym

```
pipenv install gym
```

run your code

```
pipenv run python main.py
```

This will make sure your code work without any issue.

**Other Reinforcement Learning resources**

[keras](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl) have good documented library for RL.

Good RL tutorial with tensorflow can be found [here](https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-0-q-learning-with-tables-and-neural-networks-d195264329d0).

Good Luck with your learning !!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, the output of "pipenv install gym" was "command not found"

Comment: that's because pipenv is not recoginsed as a command in your shell. Please go through the installing pipenv tutorial I mentioned before. 
https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/#installing-packages-for-your-project